# Get-IntuneManagedDevice | Out-GridView PhysicalMemoryInBytes shows 0

Tags: powershell, intune

I have created Policy Script in Intune to get my Intune Enrolled Devices inventory using this command:

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice  | Out-GridView
```

Which gives me Manufacturer, Ram, ComputerName, CPU, SerialNumber.

It perfectly works, however it doesn't give me Capacity of RAM (Always shows 0 for all devices)

I actually know an alternative solution which is getting the output of the script by the usage of MS Graph Explorer, however I don't really like this solution for I have to use postman with it. That's why I am looking for another solution.

Comment: You do not need postman.  Postman is just sending an http request and you can make an http request with powershell.

Comment: @Bahruz
Which URL are you using in Postman. When I try this URL in the v1.0 and BETA Graph API Version, for example with "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices" all my devices show "'physicalMemoryInBytes': 0"